# What is the role and historical context for "come" in "Kingdom come"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the role and historical context for "come" in ["Kingdom come"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/kingdom+come?s=t)? I've heard this said before but it seems to stick out grammatically. Is it correct?

Answer (score 7):

It's an archaism: it isn't grammatical in 21st century English to say "(thy) kingdom come" but a few centuries ago it appears to have been more common. Functionally, it is often similar to using "let" as in "(Let) thy kingdom come".

From this phrase, "kingdom come" has effectively become re-analysed as a compound noun meaning something like 'a long time in the future' or 'the beginning of the next world', mainly in the phrase "till kingdom come".

Comment: I’m reminded of Al Stewart’s lyrics in his song, “Lord Grenville”: *And **come the day** you'll hear them saying /
 "They're throwing it all away" /
 Nothing more to say /
 Just throwing it all away*

Comment: Actually, in the (Yorkshire) dialect of English that I grew up with, "come" is regularly used as a preposition in a similar way, e.g. "If you keep spending money at that rate, you'll be broke come March".

Comment: That usage sounds perfectly normal to me, growing up in semi-rural southeastern Wisconsin. I hadn’t thought of it as a preposition, and in fact, [the OED](http://www.oed.com/viewdictionaryentry/Entry/36824) has that sort of thing under the verb, in sense 36a if you can access it. It says: *“come* (present) is used with a future date following as subject, as in French *dix-huit ans vienne la Saint-Martin,—viennent les Pâques,* ‘eighteen years old come Martinmas,—come Easter’; i.e. let Easter come, when Easter shall come. *arch.* and *dial.”* I guess I too have an archaic dialect. :)

Comment: Since it takes a subject, but does not agree with it, perhaps this is some sort of fossilized subjunctive use? The citations are only from 1420–1888, so it isn’t clear where and when it passed from full, productive use into a more fossilized construct, if indeed that is what occurred.

Comment: It's possibly a slightly borderline case, but I wonder if whoever compiled that OED entry confuses historical derivation with categorisation according to the current state of the language.

Comment: Originally, this use does derive from a use of the subjunctive in Old English. There appear to be comparative cases in Old English, and the verb is clearly in the subjunctive. Of course, that's an entirely different matter to saying that instances of this derivative construction are "subjunctives" once English lost its subjunctive forms.

Comment: @tchrist Yes: it is a fossilised subjunctive form. The King James Bible (where the Lord's Prayer with this line appears) was published in 1611, right in the middle of the period cited. The Church is rather good at fossilising language in its liturgy; and from there phrases [readily enter the language](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/bible-phrases-sayings.html).

Comment: N.B. By the time of the period of the King James Bible, you have effectively the situation that you have today: English had no verb morphology that was explicitly "subjunctive"; these forms always appear identical to the infinitive as they do today. (On the other hand, in the period defined as "Old English", it did, and such subjunctive forms appear to be used in comparable cases-- so it is fair to say that the structure that survives into Middle and Modern English is a *derivative* of the previous subjunctive.)

Answer (score 4):

It's a quote of the Lord's Prayer in the Bible: "Thy kingdom come, thy will be done ..."  It is meant literally: "come" has the conventional sense of "arrive" or "get here". It is being used in the imperative, in this case in the from of a request.  It's the old Jimmy-English so the word order and punctuation are different from conventional modern English usage. In more modern English it would be, "Please make your kingdom come", or "Come please, kingdom", or, "Please send your kingdom to us."

There is a rather obsolete idiom that goes something like "I may have to wait until kingdom come for this!", meaning until God's kingdom is established and history as we know it comes to an end, i.e. for a very long time. It's not good grammar, it would make more sense to say "until the kingdom comes". But that's how idioms are. Anyway, unless you're reading an old book, I doubt you'll see that, I haven't heard it in years.

Comment: I actually just wanted to use it myself in the context of `sued into kingdom come` which is a rather common context in the south. It seems to be something you can be `knocked` or `punched` into.

Comment: N.B. It sounds a bit like an imperative to 21st century speakers, but originally it probably wasn't.

Comment: Saying it's "not good grammar" assumes that in "till kingdom come", "come" is a verb. But why assume that? If you say that "kingdom come" has been re-analysed as a noun phrase, then you just have a preposition with a noun phrase complement like any boring preposition followed by any other boring noun phrase.

Comment: As @NeilCoffey indicates, it's not an imperative in the Lord's Prayer. It's actually the subjunctive, expressing an earnest desire.

Comment: I'd probably prefer to say that the construction *derives* from subjunctive forms (from a time when English had them).

Comment: @NeilCoffey This kind of reminds me of the archaic/formulatic “Come the day...”.

Comment: @NeilCoffey English, or at least North American varieties of the same, still retains the subjunctive; in particular, the mandative subjunctive is alive and well. “I insist that she be here” means she is not here, but I want her to be. “I insist that she is here” means that I believe that she really is here, and am trying to persuade you of the same. Yes, modal alternatives (“Funny that you should say that”) are pretty common, too, but I don’t understand why you would say that English no longer has subjunctive forms. Perhaps you mean with unique/distinctive spellings, as in Old English (etc.)?

Comment: @tchrist In e.g. "They insisted that she be there", there is an alternative analysis, more satisfactory in my opinion, whereby "be" as an infinitive accompanied by a null modal. This analysis has the advantage that e.g. it better explains the syntax of "They insisted that she not be there" (whereas conjugated verb forms aren't negated in English by putting "not" before them!). If you say that it's a subjunctive form, you're proposing that English has a whole extra verb paradigm whose forms are always identical to the infinitive. The motivation for that isn't clear.

Comment: @NeilCoffey A “null” modal? Hm. In any case, the sense of the construct is the same as one in which the mandative subjunctive would be called for, so I have no trouble thinking of it as that.

Comment: @NeilCoffey As I don't speak Greek, I can't say what it was in the original. And in any case Jesus probably originally said it in Aramaic that was translated to Greek and now to English. In any case, the intent is clearly that it is a request or a wish and not an order. But the imperative is not infrequently used this way in English. Like the child who says, "Santa, bring me a bicycle!" or the bored office worker who says, "Let it be Friday". I would think the grammatical form makes it an imperative. If you want to say that the intent makes it subjuntive, hmm, maybe.

Comment: Jay: I definitely *don't* want to say that. When I said that this construction "derives" from a subjunctive in Old English, I mean the overall construction, not this specific instance in the Lord's prayer. I'm not talking about anything to do with Greek or Jesus or the Bible. I'm talking about the origin of this overall construction in *English*. It is a hangover from a time when English had subjunctive forms. But I see little case for saying that the construction as it appears in Middle/Modern English is now a subjunctive.

Comment: What made the construction a subjunctive in Old English was that e.g. the form "sie" was "sie", not "sindon"/"beon". Nothing to do with fluffy notions such as 'command', or'intent' or wotnot...!

Comment: @Neil Sorry, misunderstood your earlier post. I thought you were saying the modern English was a subjunctive.